# How to evaluate this (Fourier) integral?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

Does somebody know how to evaluate
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{e^{i\langle\xi,x\rangle}}{\|\xi\|_2^2}d\xi$$
for some given $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $n\in\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: Do you know how to do it for the case $n=1$?

Comment: Unfortunately, the linked answer does not give much detailed insight in how to compute this integral - or I just don't understand it.